# What is netinstall image?

Tags: fedora

When I try to download Fedora from the official website it provides me two options:

1. Download Live image
2. Download Netinstall images

What is the difference between them?

I just need a full install of Fedora on my laptop with GUI.

I need to download only necessary iso size image first but then later I can fully upgrade it online.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13):

A netinstall image is just a very basic system that can boot into the installer and then download everything else it needs.  You will need to have an internet connection to use a netinstall image.  You will also want to make sure your network card is supported by the kernel the netinstall image uses.

If you install with the live image you can install without an internet connection and afterwards you can set it up to pull packages from the internet rather than the installation dvd.  The end result can be exactly the same, the only difference is where your initial installation packages come from.